# Frames: remove the outer borders in IE; background transparency

Tags: css, internet-explorer, frames

Here's a sample frameset:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample frameset</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
  <frame src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame_a.html">
  <frame src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame_a.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

- How to remove the frames *outer* borders (NOT the separator resizing border between the frames) that appear in IE?
- How to set the frames background to transparent?
- If there aren't straightforward solutions to the above issues, what's a good alternative to the frameset that provides a resizing handle/border? Any different approach?

P.S. I'm working on [Real-time HTML Editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) and trying to expand its features and finally embed it on my website. Instead of using a frameset I can simply use a textarea and iframe -- no extra borders, no default white background color, very "styleable". However, a very important quality is missing: I can't resize the iframe and textarea as easily as you see on the frameset. I agree that frames are "evil", but I like the framed layout and the ability to have easily resizable content panels. Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [`allowtransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`frameborder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<frame allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">...
```

Sadly, this can't be done via CSS.

Comment: I've already tried the IE-specific attribute 'allowtransparency' and it didn't help although the transparency problem isn't only related to IE. The 'frameborder' attribute removes all the borders, not just the frame outer borders.